# What happens when i invoke apt-get install llvm?

Tags: installation, llvm, apt-get

I am curious about what happens when I invoke the following command on ubuntu 14.04 LTS

```
sudo apt-get install LLVM
```

Comment: Are you asking how `apt-get` works? Or is your question in any way related to LLVM? If so, you should clarify what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

There is a web page on the LLVM org site: https://apt.llvm.org

It explains any specific instructions for 14.04.